# Standard macOS Fontface floating "Fonts" palette not tracking "Recent Fonts"

Tags: macos, font

The standard Font palette Apple uses in many of its own macOS applications (and others) is invoked in Mail with Format > View Fonts (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).

For some reason when I change fonts it never registers in the Recent Fonts list, which is the main reason I pull this palette out usually.

Does anyone know how I can jig this into action?

I'm wanting to change font face of `inline URLs` and `code snips` to `monospaced` which I can find in the monospaced list, but to keep switching back b/w monospaced and Helvetica Neue is much easier to do if the recent fonts list is working.

---

Have to admit as a graphic designer with better font management options (Suitcase, Adobe CC) I've never liked the macOS Font palette used in most Apple software offerings, and a standard UI framework available in Xcode.

Comment: Can I ask, are you having this issue only from within Mail, or is it also happening when you Show Fonts from other apps?

Comment: Just tried BBEdit, same deal. I changed some text fonts in BBEdit to trigger it and didn't record them in the list. The list is still empty.

Comment: Also thx for the <kbd>T</kbd> edits @Monomeeth. Will use in future. That tag is peculiar to Stack Exchange I assume?